# Pyspark | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ad'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Using PySpark, I am trying to add a new column to an existing dataframe, where entries in the new column represent bin values which are closest to an existing column. In the example that I will show below the numpy array `bucket_array` represents bins (buckets).

The relevant section of the PySpark code whose error I will mention shortly is given below:

```
#Function for finding nearest bucket
def find_nearest(value, bin_array):
    bin_array = np.array(list(bin_array))
    value = float(value)
    idx = np.argmin(np.abs(bin_array - value))
    return float(bin_array[idx])
```

```
def metric_analyze(entity_peer_labeled_df, metric, delta_weeks, normalize):
    # delta_weeks = 1
    # normalize = True
    # metric : string which denotes column name
    # entity_peer_labeled_df : some Pyspark dataframe which has a column titled "pct_difference"

    bucket_array = np.arange(-1000, 1000, 5)

    udf_nearest_bin = F.udf(find_nearest, T.FloatType())    
    bucket_df = ( entity_pct_metric_df.withColumn("bucket_array", 
                              F.array(*[F.lit(i) for i in bucket_array])) ).withColumn( "pct_diff_{}_bucket".format(metric) , 
                                                                                       udf_nearest_bin("pct_difference", "bucket_array") )

    bucket_df.show()
```

When I run the above code in Jupyter notebook it works fine and I am able to see the dataframe `bucket_df`.

All the same, when I save the above mentioned code as a separate python function, import it into my Jupyter notebook and then finally execute it, I get error. I notice that the error happens at the line `bucket_df.show()`. A portion of that error is show below:

```
/mnt1/jupyter/notebooks/username/custom_function.py in metric_analyze(entity_peer_labeled_df, metric, delta_weeks, normalize)
    100                                                                                        udf_nearest_bin("pct_difference", "bucket_array") )
    101 
--> 102     bucket_df.show()

/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    376         """
    377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    379         else:
    380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
```

The full error can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u3f5L_73llZYVzi03GQSP42zXdBIjrUR/view?usp=sharing).

When I replace the line `bucket.show()` with `print( bucket.count() )`, I do not see any errors and it runs fine (even when I use the aforementioned code as a separate function ).

An example of `entity_pct_metric_df` is given below:

```
+--------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|           entity_id|. category|         sampled_ts|         some_score|         some_score_prev_value|pct_difference|
+--------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+--------------+
|abccccccccccccccc...|         A|2017-12-03 00:00:00|                192|                           824|        -632.0|
|defffffffffffffff...|         A|2017-12-10 00:00:00|                515|                           192|         323.0|
|ghiiiiiiiiiiiiiii...|         A|2017-12-17 00:00:00|                494|                           515|         -21.0|
+--------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+------------------------------+--------------+
```

How can I solve the abovementioned error?

Comment: What is `entity_pct_metric_df ` in the `metric_analyze` function? Also, can you provide examples of the variables you are using? That'll help in answering

Comment: Are you using windows? Are you running this on a cluster? `numPy` has a dependecy on `ad` which is not present

Comment: @ClockSlave : Thanks for the suggestion. I have given an example of `entity_pct_metric_df` in my recent update.

Comment: @pissall : Thanks for your suggestion. I am running this on jupyter which uses AWS. In the same jupyter notebook, I was able to run this code when it was  a part of one of the lines of the notebook (i.e. when I had not segregated the above mentioned method into a separate independent function). I saw this error after I imported this code in the jupyter notebook.

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy, your function takes `entity_peer_labeled_df ` as input. I don't know what that is and the other variables as well. Anyway, I don't think this has much to do with code. I think @pissall is pointing you in the right direction. This looks like a dependency issue.

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy, you can perhaps try importing the ad library in your segregated notebook and see if it gives you an error

Comment: @SiddharthSatpathy use a try, except Py4JJavaError block. Once you go into except block print out the error. `except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as pe: print(pe.errmsg)`. Please make the necessary imports etc and let's try to narrow down on the exact error from py4j

Comment: It is a very unusual problem to be honest